# Compile c++ Programm with CMake that uses Boost/python.hpp

Tags: python, c++, boost, cmake

I'm currently trying to compile a c++ file using CMake.
But since I'm using Boost::python it won't compile.
I set up a little test file to figure out what I need to do but I just can't get it to work.
Any Help would be greatly appreciated!!

The test file:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    namespace py = boost::python;

    Py_Initialize();

    // Retrieve the main module's namespace
    py::object global(py::import("__main__").attr("__dict__"));

    py::exec("print 'Hello from Python!' \n", global, global);

    return 0;
}
```

It will compile if I just use,

```
clang++ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7 -lboost_python -std=c++11 boosttest.cpp -o boosttest
```

I tried this CMakeLists.txt to get it to work.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_LIBRARIES(${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(Test1 boosttest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Test1 ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

and what I get is

```
undefined reference to `boost::python::import(boost::python::str)'
```

and a couple more of the same category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your help Mark, thanks to the new errors after I included

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED python)
```

I was able to figure out that the problem was that CMake selected the libs for python 3.4 but Boost was build against 2.7.

So the Solution was to include the version as so:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED python)
```

also run with verbosity to see what is going on

```
cmake . --debug-output
make VERBOSE=1
```

Comment: I just added it and now I get a new error: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyString_InternFromString'.  
Also the debug output showed that findPythonLibs apparently finds the Libs for Python 3.4